# Output limited range of integers in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm learning OCaml and am stuck with an exercise I'm trying to solve.

The exercise is to take an integer and output every even integer up to that integer like so:

Input: 5
Output: "0-2-4"

Input: 10
Output: "0-2-4-6-8"

I have to include errors for negative values, string inputs, stuff like that.

I was thinking of doing a recursive function and using pattern matching to set the edge cases and to stop the recursion.

My problem is, I'm coming from Ruby, and in Ruby my approach would be to simply make an array of integers up to the input, then modify that array with array.select, array.filter, etc., and concatenate the contents of the array into a string. I'm having much more difficulty doing something like this in OCaml.

Any tips?

Comment: What did you try? Did you try some tail recursive `let rec`? Which one? You need at least a function to output even integers less than some given `n`

Comment: I tried a basic recursive function like:

    let rec count n =
  match n with
    0 -> []
  | (n mod 2 = 0) -> n :: count (n - 2)
  
This is about as far as I get while just trying to get it to work on a basic level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your Ruby approach in OCaml, and in fact it's quite idiomatic to work this way.  Instead of arrays you would probably want to use lists.  I don't know of a built-in function to get a list of integers up to a maximum, but it's easy enough to write one.  After that, you can use `List.filter` to select the elements you want from the list.

If you're allowed to use extra libraries, there are many useful functions in [OCaml Batteries Included](http://batteries.forge.ocamlcore.org/).  After a quick look at the `BatList` module, I came up with this function for a range of integers less than n:

```
let range n = BatList.init n (fun x -> x)
```

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this to send the results of the function to a list variable but have it so I can execute from an argument in the command line.

For example, defining  the function and then saying `let list = range n` wouldn't work because it doesn't know what n is at that point.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "command line", so it's hard to give advice.  The natural thing to do if you want to use a value that you don't know what it is right now is to use a function!  In your description, `list` would be a function of `n`.

Comment: Meaning I want to export the output of `range` into a list, manipulate the list, and compile then with `ocamlc`, and then run it from the terminal with an int argument and see the printed results in the terminal.

Comment: OK, great.  The essential point is that you're dealing with a number that you don't know what it is right now.  That's exactly what functions are for.  Once you have a function that takes an int and does what you want, it's very straightfoward to create the program you describe by adding a `main` function that passes `int_of_string Sys.argv.(1)` to the function (or similar).  So I'd concentrate on writing the function first, then make the program.

Answer (score 1):

Start with something like

```
let output_even_less_then n = 
   let rec outloop i n = 
     if i < n then begin
        Printf.printf "%d\n" i;
        outloop (i+2) n
     end
   in
     outloop 0 n
```

then complete it with the input and the validity test

Comment: Is there a way to make one step in the outlook append to a list? I tried

    `let count n =
      let clist = [];
      let rec outloop i n =
  if i < n then begin
  i::clist i;
  outloop (i + 2) n
  end
  in 
  outloop 0 n
  List.iter (Printf.printf "%d - ") clist
  ;;
`

and it underlined "clist" saying the expression was not a function and couldn't be applied.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a simple `while` loop, which might be easier to understand for a start.
The functional style of the previous answers can be slightly more efficient.

```
let exercise () =
    let line = input_line stdin in
    let n =
        try int_of_string line
        with e ->
            Printf.eprintf "Could not parse line '%s'\n%!" line;
            exit 1
    in
    if n < 0
    then Printf.eprintf "%i is negative\n%!" n;
    let i = ref 0 in
    while !i < n do
        Printf.printf "%i\n" !i;
        i := !i + 2;
    done
;;

exercise ()
```